# Short story about a man remembering his father who deleted bad memories and only left the good ones

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story is about a Native American who contemplates his father. Over the years, the father underwent treatments to delete old, bad memories leaving only good ones, leaving the man smiling all day but nothing else under the surface.

IIRC, there's a twist where this entire story happens in the protagonist's head.

Comment: Can you remember when you read this?  How old the story was?  Was it a short story?